# Ethernet media converter

Tags: networking, lan, twisted.internet

Ethernet media converter works in pair A on the internet source side and B in the user side,the question is if B (user side converter) burn or damage should we change bothe side converter or not.

Is it possible to change only damage convert or both ?

Answer (score -1):

It is not necessary.  Since they are doing two different distinct tasks if B is damaged you can replace it as long as its compatible with A.